# dataflow worker failed with 'got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

running google clouds dataflow job (in Python ) failes since July 31,2019

Before July 31, 2019 running perfectly. No change in code.

Below is the error summary.

**jsonPayload:
  line: exec.go:64
  message: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

....

jsonPayload:
  line: exec.go:64
  message: TypeError

....

jsonPayload:
  line: exec.go:64
  message: serialized_pb=_b('\n\x15google/rpc/code.proto\x12\ngoogle.rpc*\xb7\x02\n\x04\x43ode\x12\x06\n\x02OK\x10\x00\x12\r\n\tCANCELLED\x10\x01\x12\x0b\n\x07UNKNOWN\x10\x02\x12\x14\n\x10INVALID_ARGUMENT\x10\x03\x12\x15\n\x11\x44\x45\x41\x44LINE_EXCEEDED\x10\x04\x12\r\n\tNOT_FOUND\x10\x05\x12\x12\n\x0e\x41LREADY_EXISTS\x10\x06\x12\x15\n\x11PERMISSION_DENIED\x10\x07\x12\x13\n\x0fUNAUTHENTICATED\x10\x10\x12\x16\n\x12RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED\x10\x08\x12\x17\n\x13\x46\x41ILED_PRECONDITION\x10\t\x12\x0b\n\x07\x41\x42ORTED\x10\n\x12\x10\n\x0cOUT_OF_RANGE\x10\x0b\x12\x11\n\rUNIMPLEMENTED\x10\x0c\x12\x0c\n\x08INTERNAL\x10\r\x12\x0f\n\x0bUNAVAILABLE\x10\x0e\x12\r\n\tDATA_LOSS\x10\x0f\x42X\n\x0e\x63om.google.rpcB\tCodeProtoP\x01Z3google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/code;code\xa2\x02\x03RPCb\x06proto3')

....

jsonPayload:
  line: exec.go:64
  message: '  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/rpc/code_pb2.py",
    line 23, in **'

Content of requirements.txt

**apache-beam==2.13.0

apache-beam[gcp]

google-cloud-iam

google-cloud-bigquery

google-cloud-storage

pyyaml**

The problem started on July 31st

Any help is appreciated.

searched for similar error and no solution.

Comment: Just to confirm, your pipeline started failing for the same Beam version (2.13.0) without upgrading any dependency ?

Comment: not sure about dependency. However, it tries to update from the requirements.txt content apache-beam==2.13.0
apache-beam[gcp]
google-cloud-core==1.0.3
google-cloud-iam
google-cloud-bigquery==1.6.1
PyYAML==3.13
six==1.12.0
pyOpenSSL
httplib2==0.12.0
google-apitools
google-api-python-client
google-cloud-storage==1.17.0

Comment: I don't think this can easily be debugged without more information regarding your job. Can you please contact Google Cloud support with this information and your job ID ?